# how does HDD indicator works

Tags: hard-drive

Sounds like a simple question, but one thing recently made me wonder:

I bought a hotswap cases for one of my boxes and they have each their own hdd activity indicator. Which works.

I always assumed that the LED is controlled by chipset which is processing the IO requests, but the HDD case is not connected to motherboard in any other way than the SATA cable itself. It's basically just in between SATA cable going to MB. So how does it know that HDD is actually transmitting data? Does it somehow get this information from signal that goes through the cable? If so, how?

Is it possible that the LED is literally hooked to data-signal cable which makes it light up when there are some impulses? Wouldn't that cause interferences or stuff like that?

Comment: "HDD case is not connected to motherboard in any way." - Yes it is.  Its connected to a hotswap case, which is SATA, which is transfering that signal to the motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you completely misunderstood me. I am not talking about LED on computer case, that is controlled by motherboard. The hotswap case has its own HDD activity indicator. Maybe you should read the whole question properly before deciding to downvote.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question.  I provided a reason for the vote, a close vote, "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.".

Comment: I think it works the same way as in case of USB drives enclosures or eSATA enclosures. However I can't tell how exactly it's done. it definitely isn't straightforward LED connection because signal level in SATA cable is almost definitely too weak to light up any LED. I think there must be just some middleware circuit that is triggered by SATA signal activity and lights up LED and passes SATA signal through. Powered by the same lines as drive itself.

Comment: @user2111737 thanks, that's pretty much what I would like to know and how it's actually done :) I think in case of USB enclosures this is different, as there is actually a convertor inside of enclosure with own processor that is processing the data signal from SATA and converts it to USB, so that one is quite clear to me. But this hot-swap enclosure doesn't seem to have anything like that, although it seems to be able to recognize the traffic on SATA cable somehow. What is even more interesting, I heard it doesn't really work for SSD drives (not sure if the power led, or activity LED though).

Comment: Although I do have 2.5'' SSD hot-swap cage at my desktop PC which also have these LEDs and they work just fine, so probably it's just some rumour.